# prevent running function on backtick angular

Tags: angular, typescript, web, string-interpolation, angularjs-interpolate

i have this syntax on angular(typescript), my problem is when this code runs, its automatically runs clickShowAttachments function, instead i am need to run function when this button clicks ...

```
${data.attachments ? `<button (click)="${this.clickShowAttachments(data.attachments)}">show attachments</button>` : ''}
```

and when it compiles, if i inspect page i see that : (click)="undefined"
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/6kEin.png)

i tried replace double quote with single quote but nothing happens ..

Answer (score 2):

I fixed it this way:

```
const a = `<button id="btn1">btn text</button>`;
document.getElementById("btn1").addEventListener('click', ()=> this.clickShowAttachments(data.attachments));
```

Comment: perfect that is what i was talking about.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting undefined because `this.clickShowAttachments(data.attachments)` returns undefined.

have you tried using

```
${data.attachments ? `<button (click)="this.clickShowAttachments(data.attachments)">show attachments</button>` : ''}
```

You can do this in angular2+

```
<button *ngIf="data?.attachments" (click)="this.clickShowAttachments(data.attachments)">show attachments</button>
```

Comment: yes, its not runs the function ..

Comment: Can you share the code on https://stackblitz.com/ what exactly you are trying to achieve that might help in helping you.

Comment: i shared above, after that backtick string, i have a function "clickShowAttachment(attachments)" witch is responsible for showing my attachments.

Comment: I hope you are using angular 2+ then you can use *ngIf="someBooleanConditionOnIt" to show or hide element conditionally. I have updated my answer.

Comment: if i do this on html file, it will be okay, but i need to store this html in ts file with backtick, which is not diffrent and probelm still be there ..

Comment: You can do it but it will not work like this, you will need to use innerHtml and pass the html content then have to apply event listener to achieve what you want.